New / different VIM for Debian?
On both my new Debian and Raspberry Pi: VIM version 9.0.1499
This vim is quite different and irksome to a user of the version that's been "standard issue" on Fedora for over a decade now. The current version I'm using is: version 9.0.1872
The biggest issue is insert mode. I'm used to just cursoring where I want to go and continuing on. But in this version doing that just creates a lot of stuff (surely they're improperly interpreted escape characters that represent the cursor keys I'm typing) that has to then be deleted after, of course, escaping out of it and start a new insert. It's a HUGE time sink. ... There are likely other less obvious differences I haven't tripped over yet - I'm a newbie to both Debian and R. Pi.
Moving over my personal .vimrc hasn't helped.
It COULD be just a .vimrc issue - I'm ignorant about what impact that might have.
So, I'm unsure how to proceed. ... nano just doesn't do it for me, too slow! I guess it's like anything else; familiarity!
So... New version? Different vimrc contents? If so what cures this insert problem? I presume it's new-version time, but if so, what version?

What does "creates a lot of stuff" actually mean?  What Vim (Vim package) are you using on Debian, exactly, and what is your TERM variable set to?  Are you using the editor in a terminal (which?) or in a non-graphical console?

Which package are you using? vim neovim nvi vim-tiny  ; note that traditional vi does not allow moving the cursor in insert mode.  I'd bet nvi doesn't support it but full vim does.

Please [edit] your question and focus it. We don't really need to know about your experience with other platforms (mentioning that you are an experienced vi user is enough), and your critique of "modern" features isn't adding any useful information, but we do need to know what the actual problem is. How exactly is insert mode unhelpful? Doing what creates what "stuff"? What is the insert problem? And

@user10489 ...I updated the Q to include the pertinent versions. Notably, on Fedora you can type vim -v and on both the others you can't - for them it's vi -v, even though they both say they're vim?!  I've never heard of nvi, neovim or vim-tiny!

From 10 years ago: https://askubuntu.com/q/434628/158442

@user10489 nvi on Debian supports moving the cursor with the cursor keys.  I don't know of any Vi implementation on Debian that doesn't.

@RichardT The -v option is only really relevant to ex, not to vim (ex -v starts ex in visual (vi) mode).  It's the --version option you want for listing compiled-in features etc.   For the ex that is distributed with nvi, the -v option does the same as for Vim's ex.

@Kusalananda I used -v to get the version - and it did that quite well?! But it ended up being confusing because as noted elsewhere it wasn't normal vim...

I surely don't understand all the downvotes. What, we're all supposed to love nano or vim-tiny? I don't get it at all. The install described below did the job. This wasn't my imagination.

From a comment by muru I found it:
It turned out I wasn't using vim at all but vim-tiny, a subset version. And thus, well, whoever did that had removed what I wanted / need.
The solution was simple:
apt install vim

and I got the normal vim I'm comfortable and productive with.

I'm using vim.tiny on Debian (and I've never found a reason to install a "bigger" Vim), and I can't reproduce your issue relating to using cursor keys.  Was that your only issue with vim.tiny?  I think this issue would be solved by ensuring that the terminal session is initialised with the correct TERM value.

@Kusalananda Gee, I don't know... Never heard of vim.tiny before. I made NO changes to any .vimrc files - or anything else at all - I just installed vim with the aforementioned apt command and "it just worked." I seriously doubt it was a TERM issue since, as I say, vim was "back to what I'm used to," though it actually still needed some of my personalizations since I don't like some of the over-highlighting. But that I can fix with .vimrc. I didn't know how to fix this insert mode cursor issue. "Reproducing it" was just entering insert cursoring up or down! It inserted unwanted chars.
